# How to create a modal dialog with Trinidad and facelets

Tags: jsf-2, dialog, servlet-3.0, websphere-8, trinidad

I am trying to create a modal dialog that pops up when a `tr:commandNavigationItem` is pressed.
I can get a pop up to appear, and when I click the "cancel" button I created, it will call the returnListener, but the pop up itself won't disappear. Calling the "submit" button causes an exception.

The website is using facelets so the calling page has a template it uses.

I get the following warnings in the log:

```
W org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponentBase getClientId getClientId should not be called while the view is being constructed. Component ID: holdOrder_hold
```

and

```
W com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.srt.SRTServletResponse setIntHeader SRVE8094W: WARNING: Cannot set header. Response already committed.
```

Here is the calling page (.xhtml):

```
<tr:navigationPane hint="bar" inlineStyle="width:100%;" id="completeNavBar">
  ...
  <tr:commandNavigationItem id="holdButton" text="#{odMessages['BUTTON_HOLD_ORDER']}" partialSubmit="true" useWindow="true" rendered="#{taskHandler.holdAndReleaseEnabled}" action="dialog:holdOrder" immidiate="true" returnListener="#{taskHandler.handleReturnHoldDialog}" windowHeight="350" windowWidth="800"/>
  ...
</tr:navigationPane>
```

Here is the complete dialog page (.xhtml):

```
<ui:composition
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
  xmlns:tr="http://myfaces.apache.org/trinidad"
  xmlns:trd="http://myfaces.apache.org/trinidad/demo"
  xmlns:trh="http://myfaces.apache.org/trinidad/html"> 
  <jsp:directive.page contentType="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
  <f:view>
    <tr:document title="Put Order On Hold">
            <tr:form>
                <tr:messages globalOnly="true"/>
                <tr:panelFormLayout>

                    <tr:inputText id="holdOrder_comment" rows="5" label="Comment:" value="#{taskHandler.task.holdObj.holdComment}" />

                    <f:facet name="footer">
                        <tr:commandButton id="holdOrder_hold" actionListener="#{taskHandler.holdToDo}" text="Submit" partialSubmit="true"/>
                        <tr:commandButton id="holdOrder_cancel" actionListener="#{taskHandler.cancelDialog}" text="cancel" partialSubmit="true"/>
                    </f:facet>
                </tr:panelFormLayout>
            </tr:form>
    </tr:document>
  </f:view>
</ui:composition>
```

Here is the single backing bean used:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class TaskHandler implements Serializable {

...

    public void holdToDo(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("putting on hold");
        HashMap<Object, Object> returnMap = new HashMap<Object, Object>();
        try {
            boolean response = ToDoHold.execute(task);

            if(!response) {

                returnMap.put("returnValue", "no validation errors");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("exception in holdToDo");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().returnFromDialog(Boolean.TRUE, returnMap);
    }

    public void handleReturnHoldDialog(ReturnEvent event) {
        System.out.println("returning hold Dialog");
    }

    public void cancelDialog(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("cancelling dialog");
        try {
            HashMap<Object, Object> returnMap = new HashMap<Object, Object>();
            returnMap.put("returnValue", "cancel");
            RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().returnFromDialog(Boolean.FALSE, returnMap);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("cancelling dialog: exception");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
...

}
```

Versions used:
Trinidad 2.0.1
JSF 2.0
Servlet 3

Comment: This is a shot in the dark, but shouldn't it be: public void cancelDialog(ReturnEvent event)

Comment: Thanks for the help! But it didn't work. cancelDialog is just a button in the dialog that should close the dialog. So I implemented that as an ActionListener on the CommandButton inside the dialog.

Changing it to accept a ReturnEvent causes an error saying it can't find the method (because the ActionListener is expecting an ActionEvent).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I never solved this completely, but it turned out that the problem was using `<f:facet name="footer">` in the dialog (the XHTML is available above) was what was causing the problem, and removing the facet caused both buttons to start working correctly. This may be a bug but I'm using a non-up-to-date version of trinidad (1.26) due to corporate guidelines.